# Find and replace strings in file with $ selectors?

Tags: regex, unix, replace, terminal

I have a file and I'm looking to use `()` to select a piece of text, and the `$1` and `$2` respectivley to replace a string.

```
http://127.0.0.1:5080/tarballs/(.+)/(.+).tgz

https://registry.npmjs.org/$1/-/$1-$2.tgz
```

How can I do this in unix? I want to run a command like this:

```
$ regex-replace ./file.txt "http://127.0.0.1:5080/tarballs/(.+)/(.+).tgz" "https://registry.npmjs.org/$1/-/$1-$2.tgz"
```

Comment: I think you could use `sed` or `awk` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
s='http://127.0.0.1:5080/tarballs/user/file.tgz'

sed -E 's~http://127\.0\.0\.1:5080/tarballs/(.+)/(.+.tgz)$~https://registry.npmjs.org/\1/-/\1-\2~' <<< "$s"

https://registry.npmjs.org/user/-/user-file.tgz
```

- DOT is special metacharacter in regex so it needs to be escaped, otherwise it will match any character.
- `~` is used a regex delimiter in `s` (substitute) command of `sed`.
- `-E` is used for extended regex support.
- `\1` and `\2` are back-references of 2 captured groups.

Comment: Whilst this is true, you should probably draw attention to some of the caveats of this approach, particularly in respect of regexp metacharacters in the search string, and `\` or the `s` separator in the search string or the replacement.

Comment: Sure, I've added it in my answer now.